# Отступ между текстом и знаком списка

Tags: html, css

Нужно уменьшить отступ между знаком списка и текстом, а так же пофиксить ширину средней ячейки и отступ второй картинки убрать

Результат

[image: Что выходит]

Ожидания

[image: Что нужно]

```css
th {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #9a99ff;
  height: 60px;
}

table {
  width: 550px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.tomsk {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

.fiol {
  background-color: #93f;
}

img {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.cvet {
  background-color: #9a99ff;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.left {
  float: left;
  width: 228px;
  color: white;
  width: 235px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: justify;
  text-indent: 20px;
}

.razm {
  width: 250px;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  color: white;
  width: 228px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  text-align: justify;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-indent: 20px;
  width: 230px;
}

h2 {
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  color: white;
  padding-left: 25px;
}

#q {
  padding: 0 5px;
}

#l {
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

#r {
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="generator" content="PSPad editor, www.pspad.com">
  <title>Лаба 1</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="laba1.css">
</head>

<body>
  <table border="1">
    <tr class="">
      <th colspan="3"><img class="tomsk" src="tomsk1.gif" alt="">
        <br clear="all">
        <h2>ВУЗы Томска</h2>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="fiol">
      <td class="razm"><img id="q" src="tgu.jpg" alt=""></td>
      <td class="razm">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <p class="p">Томский государственный университет</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p class="p">Томский университет систем управления и радиоэлектроники</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </td>
      <td class="razm"><img id="q" src="tusur.jpg" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="cvet">
      <td class="razm" colspan="3">
        <span class="left">По концентрации научно-преподавательских кадров высшей квалификации и по количеству студентов на тысячу жителей Томск традиционно занимает первое место в России</span>
        <span class="right">В томских вузах работает 5,5 тысяч преподавателей, среди которых 580 докторов наук и профессоров и 2,5 тысяч кандидатов наук и доцентов, и обучается 66,4 тыс. студентов</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="fiol">
      <td class="razm"><img id="l" src="tpu.jpg" alt=""></td>
      <td class="razm">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <p class="p">Томский политехнический университет</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p class="p">Сибирский меди-цинский университет</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </td>
      <td class="razm"><img id="r" src="med.jpg" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо добавить в стили

```
.razm {
    min-width: 250px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Это пофиксит средний столбик и отступ второй картинки.

А положение маркера можно поменять задавая элементу span

```
<li>
   <p class="p marker1">Томский университет систем управления и радиоэлектроники</p>
</li>
```

свойство margin-left с отрицательным значением,

```
.marker1
    margin-left: -15px;
```